# mySQL insert from a column and textbox in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to insert a data from a column in MySQL and a the same time a data from a texbox in VB.net to another table

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into redeem (item_no, type) values( item_no '" & cbType.Text &"')"
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: So, what happened? got any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed comma after `item_no` in value, it's something like this :

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into redeem (item_no, type) values( item_no, '" & cbType.Text &"')"
```

Comment: You should also consider using a parametrised statement to reduce risk of sql injection